# Adjusting Scrollview to Adapt to Length of Text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview, core-text

I have a scroll detail view in which I am displaying some text from a database using Core Text(iPhone and iPad). At the moment my scroll view is a default set length. However as some text entries are longer than others, this means I have a lot of white space underneath the text for some detail views.

Could anyone suggest how I can dynamically change the length of the scroll view according to the length of the text ?

All ideas welcome.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
NSString *text = @"your text from db";

CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(textview.frame.size.width, 20000.0f);

CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

textview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);

[yourScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(textview.frame.size.width,textview.frame.size.height];
```

Comment: the idea behind this is to increase size of textview according to text and giving that size to scrollview's contentSize.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
float yourDynamicHeight = 0;
for(UILabel *lbl in yourArrayOfLabels) {
    yourDynamicHeight += lbl.frame.size.height;
}
// Perhaps add some arbitrary extra height

[yourScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(yourWidth,yourDynamicHeight];
```

Note: Writing this on the go so have not compiled tested it.)

Hope it helps!